# No me hace el calculo cuando selecciono un option del select después de haber ingresado el valor con el que debe multiplicarse

Tags: javascript, fetch

Estoy haciendo una tabla donde obtengo unos datos desde la `bdd` utilizando fetch,

lo que hace la tabla es un `select` que escoge un `tipo` de usuario por así decirlo, y obtiene un valor en la misma fila (`sueldo mensual` imagen), que luego quiero multiplicar por la cantidad que yo ingrese.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La multiplicación la hace correctamente siempre y cuando:

- primero escojas una de las opciones del `select` y luego **ingreses** el **`valor` cantidad**

el **problema** es que si en un caso, el cliente quiera cambiar la opción del `select` deberá ingresar nuevamente el valor a multiplicar (cantidad) para que se actualice los valores.

donde el problema crece por que mínimo se ingresan entre 5 a 20 filas.

---

Este es mi código con lo que estoy trabajando para obtener datos con `fetch`

**Tabla:**

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select id="select_opcion_{{$cant}}" onchange="OpcionChange('select_opcion_{{$cant}}', 'select_escoger_{{$cant}}')" onkeyup="Total_manobra();">
          <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
           //aquí va un foreach con los identificador para solicitar el valor
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="number" class="cantidad_obra" onkeyup="Total_manobra();">
      </td>
      <td class="p-d" id="select_escoger_{{$cant}}">
         <input type="number" class="valor_obra" onkeyup="Total_manobra();">                
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="number" class="total_obra" onkeyup="Total_manobra();">
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Imagen de como es realmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código con el que obtengo el dato que solicito a la `bdd` :

```
function OpcionChange(identidad, receptor){
   var valor = document.getElementById(identidad).value;
  fetch('/consulta'+valor+'/opcion').then((response) => response.json()).then((response)=>{   
        document.getElementById(receptor).innerHTML=`<input type="number class="valor_obra" onkeyup="Total_manobra" value="${response.RMU}">`  
  })
}
```

---

**lo que trate de hacer** fue utilizar los `event` de `javascript` (que yo conozco y su función), pero los utilizados me daban estos problemas:

`onchange="Total_manobra();` = me calcula el valor anterior, no el solicitado.

`onclick="Total_manobra();"` = pues funcionaba pero solo si le volvía a dar clik al `select`, bueno aveces en todo caso, No es lo recomendable por que el usuario no siempre es el mismo, y el cliente (el jefe) no quiere eso.

`onkeyup="Total_manobra();"` = simplemente no funciona.

entonces estoy solicitando ayuda para ver si existe alguna forma para poder hacer eso sin problema.

---

no agrego el código de la multiplicación por que creo que ese no es el problema. en caso de que sea necesario lo agregare.

Comment: Tu explicación es confusa. Es un problema muy frecuente aquí: cuando intentas resolver un problema hay un *qué* (el problema a resolver) y un *cómo* (la forma de resolver ese problema mediante un código). El *qué* es algo muy concreto, es necesario que quienes leemos la pregunta **lo entendamos bien** y para eso debes explicarlo lo más claro posible, aislandolo del *cómo*. Muchos usuarios aquí en sus explicaciones mezclan el *qué* con el *cómo*, ese es su dilema que se convierte en un rompe cabezas porque no aplican algo tan sencillo como **separar el problema de su supuesta solución** ....

Comment: ... ¿Por qué es importante separar el *qué* (el problema) del *cómo* (la **supuesta** solución)? Porque el *cómo* puede ser erróneo, confuso, mal enfocado. Esa mezcla es lo que te lleva a veces a un callejón sin salida, porque sigues pensando que **ese es el camino**, ¿y si no lo es? En definitiva, cuando tengas un problema, explica primero el problema y luego explica la **supuesta** solución, y por qué crees que debe resolverse así. De ese modo te ayudarás a ti y a quienes pueden ayudarte. Si muchos hicieran eso encontrarían antes una solución al problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano, Ok muchas gracias por tu sugerencia, voy a tratar de editar para que sea lo mas clara posible, aunque en realidad trate de explicar a lo que pude.

Comment: ¿Por qué regeneras el input completo? 
¿Por qué no muestras el código de la función que estás llamando?
¿Por qué no llamas a la función directamente cuando obtienes la respuesta de la llamada AJAX? Creo que la solución es sencilla, pero completar un puzzle al que le faltan piezas es muy complicado

Comment: el input lo "genero" nuevamente por que estoy usando clases para los cálculos, y el código con el que genero las filas y cálculos, me marcaba error por que no encontraba esa clase y cuando quería guardar igual, la única función que no muestro es la de generar los cálculos por como dije solo es sumar filas y columnas según la clase. y el de agregar las filas pues es muy largo.

Comment: @PabloLozano igual gracias por tus preguntas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para evitar peticiones AJAX cada que se hagan cambios en los *select* te recomiendo usar [atributos de datos (dataset)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) que puedes aplicar a cada *option* y queda solo la función `Total_manobra()` para escuchar y aplicar cambios.

El evento siempre será enviado a las funciones, aunque no lo especifiques. Aprovechado eso:

- *event.target* es el elemento que disparó el evento
- Con *event.target.closest('tr')* accedes al contenedor padre
- Desde el padre *tr.querySelector('.clase_de_elemento')* puedes seleccionar los hijos por su clase
- Cuando es un *select* el disparador del evento, actualizas el valor mensual
- Solo queda realizar los cálculos necesarios

```js
function Total_manobra() {
  // Todo parte desde TR padre
  let tr = event.target.closest('tr');
  // Si el evento se disparó por cambio en select:
  if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'select') {
    // Solo se actualiza valor_obra
    tr.querySelector('.valor_obra').value = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.sueldo || 0;
  }
  // Calcular
  let cant = parseInt(tr.querySelector('.cantidad_obra').value) || 0;
  let sueldo = parseInt(tr.querySelector('.valor_obra').value) || 0;
  tr.querySelector('.total_obra').value = cant * sueldo;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Tipo</th>
    <th>Denominación</th>
    <th>Cant.</th>
    <th>Sueldo mensual</th>
    <th>Total anual</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select id="select_opcion_{{$cant}}" onchange="Total_manobra();">
          <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
          <option value="1" data-sueldo="123">SV1</option>
          <option value="2" data-sueldo="456">SV2</option>
          <option value="3" data-sueldo="789">SV3</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>Denominación</td>
      <td>
         <input type="number" class="cantidad_obra" onkeyup="Total_manobra();">
      </td>
      <td class="p-d" id="select_escoger_{{$cant}}">
         <input type="number" class="valor_obra" disabled>                
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="number" class="total_obra" disabled>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select id="select_opcion_{{$cant}}" onchange="Total_manobra();">
          <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
          <option value="1" data-sueldo="123">SV1</option>
          <option value="2" data-sueldo="456">SV2</option>
          <option value="3" data-sueldo="789">SV3</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>Denominación</td>
      <td>
         <input type="number" class="cantidad_obra" onkeyup="Total_manobra();">
      </td>
      <td class="p-d" id="select_escoger_{{$cant}}">
         <input type="number" class="valor_obra" disabled>                
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="number" class="total_obra" disabled>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Me sirve tu respuesta, igual que la primera respuesta, las dos las puedo complementar, así que dejare que se reparta la reputación, hago esto por que aprendí algo nuevo de ambas partes, espero comprendas, Gracias!

Comment: No hay problema, como dijo Pablo, lo importante es que haya un aprendizaje.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 5):

Si buscas por el id `receptor` puedes hacer algo como

```
function OpcionChange(identidad, receptor){
  let valor = document.getElementById(identidad).value;
  fetch('/consulta'+valor+'/opcion')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response)=> {
        const input = document.querySelector(`#${receptor} input`)
        input.value = response.RMU;
        Total_manobra.call(input);
  });
}
```

Una vez se ha modificado asíncronamente el valor, puedes llamar a la función Total_manobra y tendrás el valor actualizado, en lugar del cálculo con el valor anterior.

Comment: recién hago la prueba, me mandaba un error por el nombre de `Total_Manobra` lo corregí, y aparentemente funciona, tengo que hacer mas pruebas con validaciones para ver si no da problema y quiero esperar ver si alguien mas publica con otra forma, etc. En todo caso si nadie mas publica acepto la tuya como solución, Gracias.

Comment: Lo importante es que entiendas por qué funciona: se ejecuta el cálculo después de obtener una respuesta a la petición AJAX

Comment: Dejare que se reparta la reputación, la otra respuesta también es muy buena y las puedo complementar. hago esto por que los dos me enseñaron algo nuevo, espero entiendas. Gracias!.

Comment: Aquí estamos para aprender y ayudar, si consideras que la respuesta de Triby te ha ayudado más, entonces dale la recompensa porque se la merecerá

Comment: las dos son buenas, por esa razón estoy decidiendo esto de repartir.

Comment: Se reparten si tienen los mismo votos... si no, sólo se le da la mitad a la que más votos tenga

Comment: Ambas tienen los mismos votos ahora ;-)