# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de un SELECT conectado a una base de datos en HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, conexión

Tengo un pequeño formulario conectado a una base de datos donde el usaurio debe escoger distintas opciones
La base de datos tiene la tabla material que tiene los atributos:

- Id (llave primaria)
- Nombre del material
- Descripción
- Precio

Este es un combobox que jala el id del material pero al usuario le muestra el nombre del material:

```
<div class="small-group">
   <label for="deco">Material de mesas y sillas</label>
   <select name="deco">
      <?php while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){?>
      <option value="<?php echo $datos['id_m']?>"><?php echo $datos['material']?></option><?php }?>
   </select>
</div>
```

Este es el código del input donde quiero que muestre en tiempo real el precio dependiendo del material que escogió:

```
<div class="small-group">
   <label for="preme">Costo del material</label>
   <input id="preme" name="preme" type="text" value=""/>
</div>
```

Como obtengo el valor del select de arriba dependiendo de lo que el usuario haya elegido?
En el value del input tengo que hacer el código PHP para seleccionar la llave primaria y muestre el precio?

Comment: Es decir buscas que sin que se recargue la página se llene el input con el valor del select?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con Ajax.

Comment: @BetaM Si exactamente

Comment: Como te dice Alan, necesitas manejar la petición vía AJAX, busca ejemplos con Jquery o fetch

Comment: @alanfcm Podrías decirme cómo funciona Ajax?

Comment: @BetaM Ok, muchas gracias, estaré probando con eso :)

Comment: Por aqui puedes empezar https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Comment: me parece que eso lo contestaron 

$.ajax({ type:'post', url: 'prueba_consulta.php', data: datos, //data: {nombre:n}, success: function(d){ $("#idinput").val(d); } });

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM al parecer el tiene lo que estoy buscando muchas gracias

Comment: También puedes evitar peticiones AJAX usando atributos de datos (dataset) como en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/382171/no-me-hace-el-calculo-cuando-selecciono-un-option-del-select-despu%c3%a9s-de-haber-in/385948#385948)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby tu respuesta también me es muy útil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar una petición de datos desde HTML a PHP, lo puedes hacer por medio de Javascript.

En primer lugar necesitas identificar tu combobox con un *id* y crear una referencia a este elemento en Javascript, junto con tu *input* donde aparecerá el precio:

```
const combobox_material = document.getElementById('material');
const input_precio = document.getElementById('preme');
```

Después debes asociar un evento al combobox, en este caso será el evento *change*, que se lanzará cuando se seleccione una de sus opciones:

```
combobox_material.addEventListener('change', function()
{
    /* Cuando se detecte un cambio, es decir, cuando se seleccione una opción
    debes realizar una petición a tu PHP */
});
```

Para realizar peticiones a tu PHP, puedes usar la API fetch de Javascript:

```
fetch('RUT_HACIA_TU_PHP', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        id_material: this.value
    })
})
.then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
.then(function(respuesta)
{
    input_precio.value = respuesta.precio
});
```

En resumen, el código para detectar cambios en el combobox, mostrar el precio en el input y realizar la petición a PHP, sería el siguiente:

```
<script>

const combobox_material = document.getElementById('material');
const input_precio = document.getElementById('preme');

combobox_material.addEventListener('change', function()
{
    fetch('RUT_HACIA_TU_PHP', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id_material: this.value
        })
    })
    .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
    .then(function(respuesta)
    {
        input_precio.value = respuesta.precio
    });
});

</script>
```

Ahora solo falta escribir el código PHP que devuelva el precio del material consultado.